# Android:Background image

Tags: android, image, background

I am creating an application in which i need to read sdcard images. I want to put background image for the IMAGE folder, how to set that?
please reply if more info required

Comment: Go thru this link : http://www.coderanch.com/t/443531/Android/Mobile/display-Images-stored-sdcard

Comment: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/106261/backgroundimage-on-a-view-not-working-on-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;

import com.androidpeople.tab.FindFilesByType.DownloadFileAsync;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ExpandableListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener;

public class SongList extends ExpandableListActivity {
    private RingtoneAdapter expListAdapter;
    public static SongList self;

    int myProgress = 0;
    public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
    ProgressBar myProgressBar;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
    final Context myApp = this;
    // private static final String DIRECTORY = "/system/media/audio/ringtones/";
    private static final String DIRECTORY = "/sdcard/download/";

//  private MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    List<String> Ringtones = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    TextView tv, empty;
    ExpandableListView exlv1;
    // ListView lv1;
    Boolean hasErrors = false;
    int currentPosition = 0;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "TEST";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        self=this;
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        refreshList();

    }   
    }   
    public void refreshList() {

        File ringtones_directory = new File(DIRECTORY);
        if (!ringtones_directory.exists()) {
            AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(SongList.this);
            ad.setTitle("Directory Not Found");
            ad.setMessage("Sorry! The ringtones directory doesn't exist.");
            ad.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
            ad.show();
            hasErrors = true;
        }
        if (!ringtones_directory.canRead()) {
            AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(SongList.this);
            ad.setTitle("Permissions");
            ad
                    .setMessage("Sorry! You don't have permission to list the files in that folder");
            ad.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
            ad.show();
            hasErrors = true;
        } else {
            Ringtones = FindFiles(false);

            if (Ringtones.size() < 1) {
                AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(SongList.this);
                ad.setTitle("Permissions");
                ad.setMessage("Sorry! No ringtones exists in " + DIRECTORY
                        + ".");
                ad.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                ad.show();
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "No ringtones were found.");
                hasErrors = true;
            }
        }
        try {
            if (!hasErrors) {
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        SongList.this, android.R.layout.test_list_item,
                        Ringtones);
                ArrayList<String> GrouppList = new ArrayList<String>();
                GrouppList.addAll(Ringtones);
                ArrayList<ArrayList<Rington>> colors = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Rington>>();
                for (int i = 0; i <= Ringtones.size(); i++) {
                    ArrayList<Rington> color = new ArrayList<Rington>();
                    color = new ArrayList<Rington>();
                    color.add(new Rington("", "", true));
                    colors.add(color);
                }
                expListAdapter = new RingtoneAdapter(this, GrouppList, colors);
                        exlv1 = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
                            this.exlv1.setAdapter(this.expListAdapter);

            }               

        } catch (Exception e) {     
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
        }
    }

    private List<String> FindFiles(Boolean fullPath) {
        final List<String> tFileList = new ArrayList<String>();
        Resources resources = getResources();
        // array of valid audio file extensions
        String[] audioTypes = resources.getStringArray(R.array.audio);
        FilenameFilter[] filter = new FilenameFilter[audioTypes.length];
        int i = 0;
        for (final String type : audioTypes) {
            filter[i] = new FilenameFilter() {
                public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                    return name.endsWith("." + type);
                }
            };
            i++;
        }
        FileUtils fileUtils = new FileUtils();
        File[] allMatchingFiles = fileUtils.listFilesAsArray(
                new File(DIRECTORY), filter, -1);
        for (File f : allMatchingFiles) {
            if (fullPath) {
                tFileList.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
            } else {
                tFileList.add(f.getName());
            }
        }
        return tFileList;
    }// find fil

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<String> loadArray(String filename) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
            GZIPInputStream gzis = new GZIPInputStream(fis);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(gzis);
            List<String> read_field = (List<String>) in.readObject();
            in.close();
            return read_field;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Collection<File> listFiles(File directory, FilenameFilter[] filter,
            int recurse) {

        Vector<File> files = new Vector<File>();

        File[] entries = directory.listFiles();

        if (entries != null) {
            for (File entry : entries) {
                for (FilenameFilter filefilter : filter) {
                    if (filter == null
                            || filefilter.accept(directory, entry.getName())) {
                        files.add(entry);
                        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Added: " + entry.getName());
                    }
                }
                if ((recurse <= -1) || (recurse > 0 && entry.isDirectory())) {
                    recurse--;
                    files.addAll(listFiles(entry, filter, recurse));
                    recurse++;
                }
            }
        }
        return files;

    }

    public class FileUtils {

        public void saveArray(String filename, List<String> output_field) {
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
                GZIPOutputStream gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(fos);
                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(gzos);
                out.writeObject(output_field);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.getStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public File[] listFilesAsArray(File directory, FilenameFilter[] filter,
                int recurse) {
            Collection<File> files = listFiles(directory, filter, recurse);

            File[] arr = new File[files.size()];
            return files.toArray(arr);
        }
    }

}
```

The above code will list all the below contain extention files from sdcard you can change them according to your requirement Happy coding :Pragna

this is **mimetypes.xml** inside the `res` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="audio">
<item>aif</item>
<item>aifc</item>
<item>aiff</item>
<item>au</item>
<item>mid</item>
<item>mp3</item>
<item>ogg</item>
<item>snd</item>
<item>wav</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Images extends Activity  
    {  
        private Uri[] mUrls;  
        String[] mFiles=null;  

        public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)  
        {  

            super.onCreate(icicle);  
           setContentView(R.layout.images);  

           File images = Environment.getDataDirectory();  
          File[] imagelist = images.listFiles(new FilenameFilter(){  
           @override  
          public boolean accept(File dir, String name)  
           {  
               return ((name.endsWith(".jpg"))||(name.endsWith(".png"))  
          }  
       });  
           mFiles = new String[imagelist.length];  

           for(int i= 0 ; i< imagelist.length; i++)  
           {  
               mFiles[i] = imagelist[i].getAbsolutePath();  
           }  
          mUrls = new Uri[mFiles.length];  

           for(int i=0; i < mFiles.length; i++)  
           {  
               mUrls[i] = Uri.parse(mFiles[i]);     
          }     

           Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);  
           g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));  
           g.setFadingEdgeLength(40);  
       }  
       public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{  

           int mGalleryItemBackground;  
           public ImageAdapter(Context c)  {     
               mContext = c;     
           }  
           public int getCount(){  
               return mUrls.length;  
           }  
           public Object getItem(int position){  
               return position;  
           }  
           public long getItemId(int position) {  
               return position;  
           }  
           public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){  
               ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);  

               i.setImageURI(mUrls[position]);  
               i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);  
               i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(260, 210));  
              return i;  
           }     
           private Context mContext;  
           }     
       }
```

Comment: hi pragna: thanks for response,what i m looking is setting a background image to images folder